# defaults: command not found

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, command-line, defaults

i have two users on macbook pro (yosemite). one of them has access to the defaults binary in /usr/bin the other user gets command not found. looking up in /usr/bin --> no defaults. both accounts are administrators...

I have a laggy mouse (impossible to work) and i want to turn mouse acceleration off.

THX

Comment: might not fix the defaults, but could fix the mouse acceleration - http://triq.net/articles/mouse-acceleration-preference-pane-mac-os-x [last comment on there shows it still working in 2013, even though it's very old] Not tried it myself.

Comment: thx @Tetsujin, i've installed the prefpane... will evaluate it.

Comment: What do you mean by " looking up in /usr/bin --> no defaults" I read that as defaults is not in /usr/bin but in the previous sentence you say it is there